# When does encrypting an application's configuration file offer additional security?

Tags: .net, security, encryption, web-config, app-config

The .NET Framework offers the ability to encrypt (parts of) your application configuration files through the [Protected Configuration API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh8x3tas.aspx). You can for example use this to encrypt your connection strings, as to not have the username and password for the database in plaintext in your configuration file.

But what is encrypted, must be decrypted to be useful.

Using the [RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.rsaprotectedconfigurationprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) one can leverage Windows' [Cryptography Next Generation API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204778(v=vs.85).aspx) (CNG) to securely store the keys, and make it only available to select users. Alternatively one could use the [Windows Data Protection API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx) (DPAPI) to do the same.

Since both approaches are user-specific and not application-specific (the latter of which would be nigh impossible to implement), a user could write a trivial application that runs under their account, decrypts the configuration file and prints the connection string, thereby revealing the password.

So it seems that when a user has to be able to run an application (in other words, a "desktop application" in the broadest sense of the word), it makes no sense to encrypt that application's configuration, because that user can easily decrypt the configuration by themselves.

Would it then only be useful to encrypt the configuration of applications that are installed on a user's machine, but not directly run by that user? Like a Windows Service (or a Web Application hosted in a web server that's running as a service)?

That way you can give the service account permissions to read the private key, but not the end user. Of course, when the user has administrative permissions, they can grant themselves the permission to read the key, and we're back to square one.

It may also be useful for when the configuration file might fall into the wrong hands by leaving the machine in one way or another, making it unreadable outside that machine, as the keys are only stored on that particular machine.

As far as I can see, encrypting a configuration makes only sense in those two scenarios:

1. For securing configuration data of an application from a lower-privileged user working on the same machine, where that user doesn't have to execute the application directly, for example a Windows Service.
2. For preventing the configuration to be read when the file may be leaked to outside the machine through whichever means.

Is this correct, or is my train of thought flawed?

Comment: Your thinking is on the right track.  Encryption just raises the difficulty of getting the information.  I've seen it mostly commonly used in web applications so an intruder couldn't glean sensitive information easily, but if someone has gotten that far...

Comment: Exactly. IIS won't serve .config files, but you can have download code that accidentally can leak arbitrary files. By encrypting them with a key not accessible from the filesystem (...), you prevent them from actually reading the file (within a reasonable timeframe, bruteforcing might still work).